# I am trying to retrieve the each products rating and trying to display the average number but its not showing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to retrieve each product's rating and trying to display the average number of rating, but it's not showing. I am using Ionic Angular JS. So far there is no error popping out and I when through my codes many times and cannot see any issue with it.

`Add item.html`:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Add Items</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button color="primary" (click)="save()">Done</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar #searchBar (ionInput)="search($event)"></ion-searchbar>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-label>
        <h2>{{ item.id }}</h2>
        <p>Quantity: {{ item.quantity }}</p>
        <p>Average Rating: {{ averageRatings[item.id] }}</p>
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input slot="end" type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.quantity"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <!-- Other content or buttons for adding items -->

</ion-content>
```

`Add item.page.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Item } from '../shared/item';
import { ItemService } from '../shared/item.service';
import { IonSearchbar } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Loan } from '../shared/loan';
import { LoanService } from '../shared/loan.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-items',
  templateUrl: './add-items.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-items.page.scss'],
})
export class AddItemsPage implements OnInit {
  items: Item[];
  averageRatings: { [itemId: string]: number } = {};
  loan: Loan; // Declare a loan property to store the loan object

  @ViewChild('searchbar', { static: false }) searchBar: IonSearchbar;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, // Inject ActivatedRoute
    private itemService: ItemService,
    public loanService: LoanService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['loan']) {
        try {
          this.loan = JSON.parse(params['loan']);
          this.calculateAverageRatings(this.loan);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error parsing loan object:', error);
        }
      }
    });
    this.items = this.itemService.getAll();
  }

  save() {
    this.router.navigate(['/tabs/new-loan']);
  }

  search(event) {
    // Get the text typed by the user in the search bar
    const text = event.target.value;
    // Get all products again from the service
    const allProducts = this.itemService.getAll();

    if (text && text.trim() !== '') {
      // Use all products to filter
      this.items = allProducts.filter(
        item => item.id.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
      );
    } else {
      // Blank text, clear the search, show all products
      this.items = allProducts;
    }
  }

  // Calculate average ratings for items
  calculateAverageRatings(loan: Loan) {
    if (loan) {
      this.averageRatings = this.loanService.calculateAverageRatings(loan);
      console.log('Average Ratings:', this.averageRatings);
    }
  }
}
```

`detail.html`:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Loan Details</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-card *ngIf="loan">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{ loan.username }}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>

    <ion-card-content>
      <p>Status: {{ loan.status }}</p>
      <p>Due Date: {{ loan.duedate | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}</p>
      <p>Loan Items: {{ loan.items.length }}</p>

      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of loan.items">
          <ion-label>{{ item.id }}</ion-label>
          <ion-badge slot="end">{{ item.quantity }}</ion-badge>

          <!-- Rating dropdown, visible only if loan status is 'approved' -->
          <ion-select *ngIf="loan.status === 'approved'" placeholder="Rate" 
                      (ionChange)="rateItem(item, $event.target.value)">
            <ion-select-option value="1">1</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="2">2</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="3">3</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="4">4</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="5">5</ion-select-option>
          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-card-content>

    <ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteLoan()" *ngIf="loan.status === 'pending'">
      Cancel Loan
    </ion-button>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

`Detail.page.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Loan } from '../shared/loan';
import { LoanService } from '../shared/loan.service';
import { Item } from '../shared/item';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.page.scss'],
})
export class DetailPage implements OnInit {
  loan: Loan;
  averageRatings: { [itemId: string]: number } = {};

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private loanService: LoanService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Retrieve loan ID from the route parameters
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      const loanId = params.get('id');

      // Get loan details using the LoanService
      this.loanService.getLoanById(loanId).then((loan) => {
        this.loan = loan;
      });
    });
  }

  deleteLoan() {
    if (this.loan.status === 'pending') {
      this.loanService.delete(this.loan);
      this.router.navigate(['/tabs/loans']);
      // Optionally, you can navigate back to the Loans page after deletion
      // this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/tabs/loans');
    }
  }

  rateItem(item: Item, rating: number) {
    if (this.loan.status === 'approved') {
      this.loanService.addRatingToItem(this.loan.id, item.id, rating)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Rating added successfully');
          // You might want to update the local item's ratings array here
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
  }

  // Add a method to calculate average ratings for items
calculateAverageRatings(loan: Loan): { [itemId: string]: number } {
  const averageRatings: { [itemId: string]: number } = {};

  for (const item of loan.items) {
    if (item.ratings && item.ratings.length > 0) {
      const totalRating = item.ratings.reduce((acc, rating) => acc + rating, 0);
      const average = totalRating / item.ratings.length;
      averageRatings[item.id] = average;
    } else {
      averageRatings[item.id] = 0; // Set default to 0 if no ratings
    }
  }

  return averageRatings;
}

navigateToAddItemsPage() {
  // Pass the averageRatings along with the loan when navigating
  this.router.navigate(['/tabs/add-items'], { queryParams: { loan: JSON.stringify(this.loan) } });
}
}

loan.service.ts
 // Add a method to get an item's average rating
  getAverageRating(item: Item): number {
    if (item.ratings.length === 0) return 0;
    const total = item.ratings.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
    return total / item.ratings.length;
  }

  // Add a method to calculate average ratings for items in LoanService
calculateAverageRatings(loan: Loan): { [itemId: string]: number } {
  const averageRatings: { [itemId: string]: number } = {};

  for (const item of loan.items) {
    if (item.ratings && item.ratings.length > 0) {
      const totalRating = item.ratings.reduce((acc, rating) => acc + rating, 0);
      const average = totalRating / item.ratings.length;
      averageRatings[item.id] = average;
    } else {
      averageRatings[item.id] = 0; // Set default to 0 if no ratings
    }
  }

  console.log('Average Ratings:', averageRatings); // Debugging: Log average ratings
  return averageRatings;
}
```

I just want my average rating to display. I have been trying to solve for a couple days straight but to avail. Please help if possible